# Greatest common divisior of $2^n$ and $\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Find the greatest common divisior of $2^n$ and $\binom{2n}{n}$.
As I assume we have to use identities

$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k} = 2^{n}$ and $\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}^2 = \binom{2n}{n}$.

But I cannot find the connection between $\gcd((a_1+...+a_n),(a_1^2+...+a_n^2))$? Any hints how do we find such thing?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_formula

Comment: I doubt you'll be able to use those formula to get much of anything, because the formula is actually rather complicated in terms of $n$.

Comment: Now I know that my way would not work :( Thanks although.

Comment: You might find some related results by investigating Catalan numbers, $\frac{\large 1}{\large n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Legendre's formula, $v_p(k!)=\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {[\frac{k}{p^i}]}.$The power of 2 in the binomial is therefore $v_2((2n)!)-2v_2(n!)=n-\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} {[\frac{n}{2^i}]}=A<n.$So the gcd is $2^A$ and I don't think A can be simplified.

Comment: It can be given a simple description: $A$ is the sum of the digits in the binary representation of $n$.

Comment: @Winther, That is the ultimate answer.

Answer (score 3):

[Kummer's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kummer's_theorem) gives you the following answer. Write $n=\sum_{i=0}^kb_i2^i$ in base two, i.e. $b_i\in\{0,1\}$ for all $i$.

Then do grade school addition of $n+n$. Let the number of carries be $\ell$. Then, according to Kummer,
$$
\gcd(2^n,\binom{2n}n)=2^\ell.
$$
Kummer's theorem follows in a relatively straightforward manner from [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre's_formula) mentioned by Will Jagy.

---

For example, when $n=13=1101_2$, you do the addition
$$
\begin{array}{r}1101\\1101\\ \hline11010\end{array}.
$$
You see that there were carries into positions $2^1,2^3$ and $2^4$. Three carries total, so we get that $\binom {26}{13}$ is divisible by $8$ but not by $16$.

Comment: As commented by Winther under Bogdan Simeonov's answer, in this particular case: $p=2$, $\binom{2n}n$, the number of carries is equal to the number of $1$s in the binary expansion of $n$.

Answer (score 2):

If we write

$${2n\choose n}=\frac{(2n)!}{n!\cdot n!}$$

then can you work out how many factors $2$ are in ${2n\choose n}$?

Hint:

> Note that $\frac{(2n)!}{n!\cdot n!}=\frac{(n+1)\cdot (n+2)\cdots (2n)}{1\cdot 2\cdots n}$. How many factors $2$ do the numbers $1,2,\cdots,n$ have compared to $(n+1),(n+2),\cdots (2n)$?